# PHP get site title from multiple URLs

Tags: php, html, regex, dom

I have a bunch of links. I need to extract the title from them. So, I want to make textarea to paste links and button like "get the title" to extract titles. I made a function to extract the title from one URL. It works fine. I'm a newbie in PHP and I don't know how to detect line break to get urls. Could anyone help me?

This is my code

```
<?php
 function getTitle($url) {
 $data = file_get_contents($url);
$title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $data, $matches) ? $matches[1] : null;
return $title;
 }

 echo getTitle('http://example.com');
 ?>
```

Comment: Maybe an [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: Are you using form submit or ajax to send textarea content

Comment: I'm using form submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **preg_split()** for them.

```
$urls = $_REQUEST['urlArea'];

function getTitle($url) {
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $data, $matches) ? $matches[1] : null;
    return $title;
}

// split by new-line character(\r\n or \r or \n)
$arr_url = preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $urls);

foreach($arr_url as $url) {
    echo getTitle($url);
}
```

**EDIT** : your function added for full code

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work but it doesn't echo any title. My code for now

function getTitle($url) {
    $urls = $_REQUEST['urlArea'];
    $arr_url = preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $urls);
    foreach($arr_url as $url) {
        echo getTitle($url);
    }
}

Comment: you called getTitle() function recursively. I edited my answer with full code

Comment: Hell yeah! This is what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MMPL1 it's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. When we get the data by using function `file_get_contents` we should check the length of that data.

```
 function get_title($url){
      $str = file_get_contents($url);
      if(strlen($str)>0){
        $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str)); // supports line breaks inside <title>
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title); // ignore case
        return $title[1];
      }
    }
    //For Example:
 echo get_title("stackoverflow.com/");
```

The output is:

```
Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
```

Comment: Well this is exactly what I have for now. I want to paste multiple url's like

example.com
otherexample.com etc.

and then output title's for them

example1 title
otherexample title